# GNU Make : Why makefile.head and makefile.tail

Tags: makefile

I'm reading `live555` RTSP/RTP Server source code. in this library, i see that author breaks makefile into two part : `makefile.head` and `makefile.tail`. and in script to build this library, there is a line :

```
cat Makefile.head ../config.$1 Makefile.tail > Makefile
```

If I understand true, this line means : append content of `makefile.tail` into `makefile.head` and become `makefile`. nothing special.

Do I understand true ? If true, why author do this instead of write only one makefile ?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cat Makefile.head ../config.$1 Makefile.tail` concatenates three files - `Makefile.head`, `../config.$1` ($1 is variable, likely taken from arguments) and `Makefile.tail`. Reason is that you can have many different `config.*` files, but current configuration wants to use only one (and very specific one) of them - e.g. one config for each operating system, compiler, or whatever.